# Full screen Flash problems

Tags: flash

When I play Flash videos from sites such as YouTube, the videos initially play ok. However when the videos are full screened, a number of problems arise. Usually when the full screen button is first clicked, the video will take up the full screen, but will be frozen (however the video audio can still be heard).

It can take several attempts to get the video to play in full screen. The video is also frozen if something triggers notify-osd (changing the volume, getting a new email etc.)

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Comment: Are you using chrome? I have had similar problems with Chrome, and have had much better luck using Firefox, I have not been able to find a fix so for now I am just using firefox for anything that involves flash... Sucks.. but that is the way it is I guess

Comment: EXACTLY the same issues for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known Bug,

See this [Cannot watch youtube in fullscreen mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13238/cannot-watch-youtube-in-fullscreen-mode)

```
sudo mkdir /etc/adobe
echo "OverrideGPUValidation = 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/adobe/mms.cfg
```

Comment: nice fix. cheers.