# Flash video fails to go full screen

Tags: 12.04, unity, video, flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

I have tried the fixes in [Full screen Flash problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26717/full-screen-flash-problems?rq=1) and [Video's won't go into full screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157437/videos-wont-go-into-full-screen?rq=1) and none of this solved my problem.

In YouTube, if I click quickly on the "full screen" button many times, eventually it will "stick" and stay in full screen. But I am watching a different flash video player (URL: http://www.ewtn.com/Live/unicorn/jwplayer.asp?feed=domeng) and no matter how many times I click, it won't stay in full screen - it flashes briefly and then collapses back to a window. Ubuntu 12.04; desktop Unity; browser Chrome 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux); Flash - "Version: 11.2 r202" NPAPI.

Comment: I will note that, keeping in mind previous mentions of bugs in this area, my Displays control panel claims that my screen is a "Laptop" when it is indeed a desktop LCD monitor (Samsung 22" 1680x1050)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Google Chrome? Then you're using Google's implementation of Flash called Pepper. Pepper has a bug where flash videos cannot go fullscreen.
[Chrome fails to render Flash video in full-screen correctly](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133599&q=pepper%20fullscreen&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Feature%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS)
Go to about:plugins in the chrome omnibar.
Then, on the right side click Details and disable the flash plugin PPAPI and use the Mozilla plugin. Hopefully it gets fixed in an upcoming Chrome release.
EDIT: This appears to be fixed in Google Chrome v21.

Comment: I am using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 (Developer Build 134367 Linux) Ubuntu 12.04

about:plugins says Flash - "Version: 11.2 r202" NPAPI.

Comment: Just tested it in Firefox 14.0.1 and it fails in the same way, so it ain't Chrome that is causing this.

Comment: This bug was fixed in my upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10. Flash video now obediently goes full-screen no matter what site I visit.Thanks for the help.